# JS Таблица с input и заполнением полей

Tags: javascript, html, html5, table

Добрый день, имеется таблица в которой одно из полей input при заполнении которого(при потере фокуса), значение этого инпута надо помножить на значение в соседней ячейке и вывести результат в следующую ячейку. Вобщем это обычная табличка: количество*цена=сумма.
В JS слаб, помогите пожалуйста.

Пример таблицы на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dumb/5wgyfmee/1/)

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="table-price-box">
 <tr>
  <td>Наименование</td>
  <td>Классификатор</td>
  <td>Свойства</td>
  <td>Количество</td>
  <td>Цена</td>
  <td>Итого</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Корпус</td>
  <td>ТТБ</td>
  <td>Пластик</td>
  <td><input onchange="" type="number"></td>
  <td>88</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Корпус</td>
  <td>ТТБ</td>
  <td>Пластик</td>
  <td><input onchange="" type="number"></td>
  <td>88</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Корпус</td>
  <td>ТТБ</td>
  <td>Пластик</td>
  <td><input onchange="" type="number"></td>
  <td>88</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Корпус</td>
  <td>ТТБ</td>
  <td>Пластик</td>
  <td><input onchange="" type="number"></td>
  <td>88</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Корпус</td>
  <td>ТТБ</td>
  <td>Пластик</td>
  <td><input onchange="" type="number"></td>
  <td>88</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Корпус</td>
  <td>ТТБ</td>
  <td>Пластик</td>
  <td><input onchange="" type="number"></td>
  <td>88</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Корпус</td>
    <td>ТТБ</td>
    <td>Пластик</td>
    <td><input onchange="" type="number"></td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("table-price-box").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  var inp = e.target;
  
  if (inp.tagName === "INPUT") {
    //var tr = inp.closest("tr");
    var tr = inp.parentElement.parentElement;
    tr.querySelector(".sum").textContent = tr.querySelector(".price").textContent * inp.value;
  }
});
```

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="table-price-box">
  <tr><td>Наименование<td>Классификатор<td>Свойства<td>Количество<td>Цена<td>Итого</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Подскажите ещё можно ли средствами js динамически изменять значение ячейки цена в зависимости от значения в input? К примеру до 50 цена 88, от 50 до 100 цена 77

Comment: @Dumb, конечно можно.

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз ваш вариант подходит лучше так как имеются столбцы с rowspan. Подскажите как реализовать динамическую смену значения ячейки "цена" от значения input. И как можно вывести сумму всех значений всех ячеек "Итого" в произвольный <div>?

Comment: @Dumb, а в чём именно заключается проблема? И предлагаю задать отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Навскидку, если можно c jQuery

```
$('#table-price-box input').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
  var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
  var cnt = parseFloat($this.val());
  var price = parseFloat($tr.find('td:eq(4)').text());
  $tr.find('td:eq(5)').text((cnt * price).toFixed(2));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w3jnorqb/1/

Comment: Спасибо большое. Подскажите ещё

Comment: Ну вот... А я уже без jQuery сделал...

Comment: У таких `'td:eq(4)'` селекторов так себе производительность. В данном случае можно отдать браузеру `nth-child`. И `parseFloat` зло. Да ещё и не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Подскажите ещё можно ли средствами js динамически изменять значение ячейки цена в зависимости от значения в input? К примеру до 50 цена 88, от 50 до 100 цена 77

Comment: $tr.find('td:eq(4)').text(cnt < 50 ? '88' : '77');

Comment: блин, по Enter отправилось. Хотел дописать что боязнь несоответствия типов у меня из других ЯП :)